How to Make Axis Extend Beyond Plot
The following code plots a function with the axes styled red with arrowheads.
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 10, GridLines -> All, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0.03]}, {Red, Arrowheads[0.03]}}]


I would like to figure out a way to extend the axes so that they extend beyond the plot window (outside the gridlines).  The axes should look something like I've drawn below.

Any ideas?

Perhaps look at Epilog in the Plot documentation and then look at Epilog by itself in the documentation. See if you can get that working first without extending past the edges of the plot and then see if you can push it beyond the edges. Also look at ImageMargins in the Plot documentation which might relate to this. Sometimes using Show to combine two different graphics objects can accomplish things.

Similar to Daniel's except using PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> {{15, 25}, {20, 25}} and full arrows
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 ImagePadding -> {{15, 25}, {20, 25}},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> 10,
 AxesStyle -> Red,
 Prolog -> {
   LightGray,
   AbsoluteThickness[1],
   Line[Flatten[
     Table[{{{-10, i}, {10, i}}, {{i, -10}, {i, 10}}}, {i, -10, 10}], 
     1]],
   Red,
   AbsoluteThickness[1.25],
   Arrow[{{-0, -10.75}, {-0, 11.5}}],
   Arrow[{{-10.75, 0}, {11.5, 0}}]}]



There is no ready made function for this. You must roll your own. Here is something to get you started:
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRangePadding -> 2, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesStyle -> {{Red}, {Red}}, 
 Prolog -> {Thickness -> 0.001, 
   Line[Flatten[
     Table[{{{-10, i}, {10, i}}, {{i, -10}, {i, 10}}}, {i, -10, 10}], 
     1]], Red, Arrow[{{0, 10}, {0, 12}}], Arrow[{{10, 0}, {12, 0}}]}]


